# Take picture from linear layout and save to gallery

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

How can I take picture from LinearLayout and save it to gallery? For example my LinearLayout name is `ll` I want to take picture from `ll` and save it to the gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to take photo from your mobile desktop programmatically ?if so use intent to take photo.you can search the net for intent to take photo. 
you can use this block of code.

```
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;    
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my english is not good i do not know what i shod searching!! can you help me?

Comment: of course i pasted a block of code for you please try it